# How to download a video from a link in php?

Tags: php, laravel, youtube

I made a script that extracts a url from a youtube video, and when I

```
<a href="{{ $versions[$i][$url] }}" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-download"></i> HD (720p)</a>
```

where $versions[$i][$url] is the stored url:

```
https://r8---sn-gvhuxax-cc0r.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1590431934&ei=XrzLXsXhDsqc1gKnm7HgBg&ip=92.80.254.101&id=o-ALo4VqjxLqK_kE0GSmybAZmzM1GtKW5i1LWqIC_fU93k&itag=22&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=op&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-gvhuxax-cc0r%2Csn-4g5e6nez&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=7&pcm2cms=yes&pl=24&initcwndbps=780000&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&ratebypass=yes&dur=637.387&lmt=1583654848288348&mt=1590410252&fvip=1&c=WEB&txp=5532432&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cratebypass%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIgMLvDQDZY2hHBfKqwDwLPW4CeG5a6RxXYFrz6OEqNVQ8CIQCnOyaprdi1jJJAKpqapchZ6zMfjiC0repEdcjBfA7Rqw%3D%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpcm2cms%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIgKRpbr5ke6Ezsn0J8gbnPjTuU9OactCsdbokAMKzPoqECIQCTzXwyTkWFS4onQeDDf4Xrj4m8tH0TVSY8QnXdieB-lA%3D%3D
```

I want to start a download from here when a user click on that link, not to redirect to a video type header. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it just adding "download" to your <a> tag?

Comment: No, wtf. I tried 3 times, this doesn't work.
```<a href="{{ $versions[$i]['url'] }}" class="btn btn-success" download="{{ $video_title }}.mp4"><i class="fas fa-download"></i> HD (720p)</a>```

Comment: I meant without adding a link.. Like this: `<a href="{{ $versions[$i]['url'] }}" class="btn btn-success" download><i class="fas fa-download"></i> HD (720p)</a>`

Comment: Yes, i tried this too. ```<a href="{{ $versions[$i]['url'] }}" class="btn btn-success" download><i class="fas fa-download"></i> HD (720p)</a>```. Try it to yourself with the link provided in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your link contains restricted content that not allowed downloaded by another IP or referer. You should download your link to your server first then generate your own download link.